# Apache commons utilities to convert delimited string into Array?

Tags: apache-commons

I have a user input string that are delimited by `newline`, are there any apache commons utilities i can use to convert them into an array or list?

```
1518778598
1518779069
1518779097
1518779074
1518779107
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found another way of doing so, using Apache Commons Lang `StrTokenizer`.

```
String mystr = str;
String[] strArr;

StrTokenizer st = new StrTokenizer(mystr, delimiters);
// do not add empty tokens
st.setIgnoreEmptyTokens(true);

// get token list
strArr = st.getTokenArray();
```

Comment: Great thing is that you can also call `List<String> strArr = st.getTokenList()`.

Answer (score 1):

How about **split** in org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils?

Answer (score 1):

Here is sample code, you will need Apache Commons Lang library:

```
    import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

public class SplitTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String input = "1518778598\n1518779069\n1518779097\n1518779074\n1518779107";

        String[] split = StringUtils.split(input, '\n');
        for(String str : split) {
            System.out.println("Had: " + str);
        }
    }
}
```

This results in

```
Had: 1518778598 
Had: 1518779069 
Had: 1518779097 
Had: 1518779074 
Had: 1518779107
```